# Python Inheritance - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a example of inheritance and don't know why my output is not correct. Below is the code.

```
class BankAccount():
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance=0

    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance += amount
        print(self.balance)

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        print(self.balance)


class MinimumBalance(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,min_bal):
        BankAccount.__init__(self)
        self.min_balance=min_bal

    def withdraw(self,amount):

        if self.balance - amount < self.min_balance:
            print("Balance is LOW")
        else:
            BankAccount.withdraw(self,amount)

a=BankAccount()
b=MinimumBalance(50)
a.deposit(100)
b.withdraw(40)
```

The output is:

```
100
Balance is LOW
```

Comment: So what output did you expect instead?

Comment: you are saving on wrong instance. a=BankAccount()
b.deposit(100)
b.withdraw(40)

Comment: I don't think inheritance does what you think it does. `a=BankAccount(); b=MinimumBalance(50)` creates *two* objects. `a` is of type `BankAccount` and `b` of type `MinimumBalance`. Depositing to `a` only changes `a`'s internal state, not that of the class `BankAccount` and certainly not of any instance of `MinimumBalance`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MinimumBalance(50)` instance has a balance of 0. The `a` object is independent, it is a separate instance, it doesn't matter what balance that entry has. The `MinimumBalance()` class has all the functionality of `Balance`, with some tweaks, so you just interact with the `b` instance entirely.

Deposit a balance on `b` instead:

```
b = MinimumBalance(50)
b.deposit(100)
b.withdraw(40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inheritance construction is right, however you have made two objects. MinimumBalance is now also a BankAccount but with a different withdraw function. You should call it BankAccountWithMinimumBalance instead which is what it is. Then instead of making two objects, you just make a BankAccountWithMinimumBalance and use that.